# ¿Cómo filtrar objetos de un array en VueJS?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Estoy tratando de realizar un input de autocompletado y quiero filtrar los resultados, filtra pero **solo el primer objeto que encuentra** y necesito que encuentre por ejemplo todos los que empiezan con **p**

me podrian apoyar por favor

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: '',
    routes: [
      { id: 1, name: "perfil" },
      { id: 2, name: "perfil2" },
      { id: 3, name: "menu"},
      { id: 4, name: "menu2"}
    ],
    filter: []    
  },
  methods: {
    filterResults ( value ) {
      const search = this.routes.filter(route => route.name === value);
      this.filter = search
      console.log(search)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <input type="text" v-model="value" placeholder="Buscar" @input="filterResults(value)"/>
    <li v-for="(route, id) in filter" :key="id">{{ route.name }}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: En el `filter()` no estás buscando los _que empiezan con "p"_ estás buscando una coincidencia exacta. Probá con: `route => route.name.startsWith(value)`.

Comment: @azeós, deberías publicarlo como respuesta y, de preferencia, hacerlo insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tenés en el `filter()`. Estás buscando una coincidencia exacta de la palabra ingresada. Para buscar los que "empiezan con P" podes usar [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/startsWith).

Por otro lado, para hacer que la búsqueda no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, comparo los nombres con el valor ingresado, pero pasando ambos a minúsculas con [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toLowerCase).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: '',
    routes: [
      { id: 1, name: "PeRfIl" },
      { id: 2, name: "perfil2" },
      { id: 3, name: "menu"},
      { id: 4, name: "MENU2"}
    ],
    filter: []    
  },
  methods: {
    filterResults ( value ) {
      this.filter = this.routes.filter(route => route.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()));
      console.log(this.filter);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <input type="text" v-model="value" placeholder="Buscar" @input="filterResults(value)"/>
    <li v-for="(route, id) in filter" :key="id">{{ route.name }}</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar match (que te devuelve todos los valores que contenga P), no importa si en el medio, final o comienzo o startsWith

```js
     new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        value: '',
        routes: [
          { id: 1, name: "perfil" },
          { id: 2, name: "perfil2" },
          { id: 3, name: "menu"},
          { id: 4, name: "menu2"}
        ],
        filter: []    
      },
      methods: {
        filterResults ( value ) {
          const search = this.routes.filter(route => route.name.match(this.value.toLowerCase()));
          this.filter = search
          console.log(search)
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
         <input type="text" v-model="value" placeholder="Buscar" @input="filterResults(value)"/>
        <li v-for="(route, id) in filter" :key="id">{{ route.name }}</li>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tendrías que pasar a lower case también el nombre, antes del `match`. Sino si el nombre tiene mayúsculas nunca va a haber una coincidencia.

Comment: si tambien, gracias por recordarlo!